# JavaScript function to format text

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have something like that in my ASP.NET MVC View page.

```
<li>Status: <span id="serviceStatus">formatServiceAvaibility(@service.Avaiable);</span></li>
```

service is stronly typed object. And function:

```
function formatServiceAvaibility(serviceStatus) {
    if (serviceStatus == true)
        return 'ON';
    return 'OFF';
}
```

Why this doesn't work while loading page?
Result is: Status: formatServiceAvaibility(True);

How to make that?

Comment: Please make sure, your function is getting called.. try with an alert, what is the value passed in it.

Answer (score 2):

That may be because c# formats bool with a capital letter. Try to change the code to

```
formatServiceAvaibility(@(service.Avaiable ? "true" : "false"));
```

or

```
formatServiceAvaibility(@(service.Avaiable.ToString().ToLower()));
```

Comment: <li>Status: <span id="serviceStatus">myF(@service.Avaiable.ToString().ToLower());</span></li>  function myF(serviceStatus) {
        if (serviceStatus == 'true')
            return 'ON';
        return 'OFF';
    }; still not working

Comment: Inside the function, serviceStatus is of type bool and when comparing, the value `'true'` needs to be without apostrophes. It is because when the value was passed into the function it was not wrapped into apostrophes.